# С чего начать реализацию логов парсера на python?

Tags: python, sql, pymysql

Всех приветствую ! Есть парсер который парсит новостные ресурсы.

### **Стоит задача:**

Реализовать логи для парсера и записывать эти логи в отдельную таблицу в БД.

### **Вопросы:**

1.Какую  лучше структуру  создать для таблицы логов.

2.Как это лучше реализовать логи для парсера в моем коде.

**Код:**

```
import requests
import pymysql
import dateparser
import schedule
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# < Получаем html код.
def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text

# < Получаем ссылки.
def get_resource_links(resource_page,links_rule,resource_domain):
    resource_links = []
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resource_page,'lxml')
    resource_links_blocks = soup.find_all(links_rule[0],{links_rule[1]:links_rule[2]})
    for resource_link_block in resource_links_blocks:
        a_tag = resource_link_block .find("a")
        if a_tag:
            link = a_tag.get("href")
            resource_links.append(resource_domain + link)
    return resource_links

# < Собираем заголовки с страницы.
def get_item_title(item_page,title_rule):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(item_page, 'lxml')
    item_title = soup.find(title_rule[0],{title_rule[1]:title_rule[2]})
    return item_title['content']

# < Собираем даты с страницы.
def get_item_datetime(item_page,datetime_rule,datetime1_rule):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(item_page, 'lxml')
    item_datetime = soup.find(datetime_rule[0],{datetime_rule[1]:datetime_rule[2]})
    if item_datetime is not None:
        item_datetime = soup.find(datetime_rule[0],{datetime_rule[1]:datetime_rule[2]}).text
        item_datetime = dateparser.parse(item_datetime, date_formats=['%d %B %Y %H'])
    else:
        if (len(datetime1_rule) == 3):
            item_datetime = soup.find(datetime1_rule[0],{datetime1_rule[1]:datetime1_rule[2]}).text
            item_datetime = dateparser.parse(item_datetime, date_formats=['%d %B %Y %H'])
        else:
            item_datetime = ''
    return item_datetime

# < Собираем контент с страницы.
def get_text_content(item_page,text_rule,text1_rule):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(item_page, 'lxml')
    item_text = soup.find(text_rule[0],{text_rule[1]:text_rule[2]})
    if item_text is not None:
        item_text = soup.find(text_rule[0],{text_rule[1]:text_rule[2]}).text
    else:
        if (len(text1_rule) == 3):
            item_text = soup.find(text1_rule[0],{text1_rule[1]:text1_rule[2]}).text
        else:
            item_text = ''
    return item_text



# < Подключение к базе данных.
connection = pymysql.connect(host = 'localhost',
                             user = 'root',
                             password = '',
                             db = 'news_portal',
                             charset = 'utf8',
                             autocommit = True)
cursor = connection.cursor()

# < Запрос правил выдергивания из таблицы resource контента.
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM `resource`')
resources = cursor.fetchall()

# < Цикл для перебора из кортежа.
for resource in resources:
    resource_name = resource[1]
    resource_link = resource[2]
    resource_url = resource[3]
    link_rule = resource[4]
    title_rule = resource[5]
    datetime_rule = resource[6]
    datetime1_rule = resource[7]
    text_rule = resource[8]
    text1_rule = resource[9]
    print(resource_name)
    resource_domain=resource_link
# < Разбиваю данные из кортежа в массив.
    links_rule = link_rule.split(',')
    title_rule = title_rule.split(',')
    datetime_rule = datetime_rule.split(',')
    datetime1_rule = datetime1_rule.split(',')
    text_rule = text_rule.split(',')
    text1_rule = text1_rule.split(',')
    resource_page = get_html(resource_url)
    resource_links = get_resource_links(resource_page,links_rule,resource_domain)
    print('кол-во ссылок: '+str(len(resource_links)))

# < Цикл для вызова функции.
    for resource_link in resource_links:
        item_page = get_html(resource_link)
        item_title = get_item_title(item_page,title_rule)
        item_datetime = get_item_datetime(item_page,datetime_rule,datetime1_rule)
        item_text_content = get_text_content(item_page,text_rule,text1_rule)

        try:
            # < Запись новостей в БД.
            sql = "insert into items (`item_link`,`item_title`,`item_datetime`,`item_text_content`) values (%s,%s,%s,%s)"
            cursor=connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute(sql,(str(resource_link),str(item_title),str(item_datetime),str(item_text_content)))
            print('Запись в базу данных успешно завершена!')
        except pymysql.err.IntegrityError:
            print('ah shit ! duplicate error!')
            break
        except pymysql.err.InternalError:
            print('ah shit ! error')
            break
connection.close()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43843623/5741205

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответы:

1. Вот такая структура подойдет.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Вот такие строчки кода добавил.

В  начале кода:

> ```
> created = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
> start_time = time.time()
> ```

В конце:

> ```
> duration = time.time()-start_time # время работы в секундах
> finished = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
> ```